# Removing Duplicates in Axios React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, duplicates

This is my code to display all the bond actors and directors, but when displaying, it has multiple of the same names, and I want to remove the duplicates.
**Prettier 2.7.1**
[Playground link](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBLAtgBwgJxgAgCU4BDMGAGn2HwFcBnOAZRhPnwF98AzHCdfAB0QOUuWEBuQVAzY8+ejACeAGzgATHnwHDFqjQFpIWaAhj1J02bgIkAHqgj0t-ISHuOLIKVGmQoivgAQrQwMND4ALwKymrqAHQARqHhUAAG0vhZ+IlkANYA5ny0UOpGECq4SDkq+T7Z+JCVONUA7gAWqPD12dzQMAb0qABecNUATAAMmHY9WZgk6uqoUAXVAIzTdvgAbFtzObjqcDgGOIuoDNUArDMH6CQ4BSsbW-j7mdlgtDj0VfjYFbwHA9NI+aTSbglciOKDBFLQADCKlQYDyAAoAJTUT4QuGNaCBADaDBO9CojBgAFVGL8ALpROiMFhsOBYnr+QLcOAwMDtAAibBIjPRykwcGxkQAfDj8VkPE54gUeejhO0wph6EgAPTakZQbgAR3oAE5xlAAMzxOB2ODfeAGEiYVDxBgGVpwRQGdbxEgPYbQEitejxYza44AN21TtQ2oj4216AgEdQnuEmM+DXiMHaCHR6NE9GwAQlURlwEzDQUPJpZPRNCJYrgdOqAEEcOclPFePx0VA4K18EwVYXi4x4uohZjMRxMQcsrOehxwfjRDAfnDVXL8AAeZYRqWVrJ71AHo-ZHftcZSoLQTSC1i5Rg77VXw-bhqX65S5GovL4CIczgHIEQCfBwmrYCgPwFFAggbh8BIFQVHA3NDlKfAkxTOAAHJnGWURyFwcl0M0Mhwl+KhRDUEhGHwJRSBwKgSAwmAujUBRoAKegX3ab88SrC8QjCCIkRRNFImALEyx4Hk+QfEhVRARI7wAfXI3B0w4G873wVsiN+F9hNSd9BKyYBSV+fAADJrPwLczIvWgVFMxzsgs2l6AAfiSNSNJwHyHkwfNLMlGUHLcz8UXwPI4CUSTLPiVB1G0jyTl80p1IMjgXxRVzIunDhz0-bVnPyqsZ3PF993K48auK3djNEqBfwkqSwtk3kBSFJSCLtCivBnKV+VQQiBqM0DavcyznFs+yGuPMqFumzyfL6gzvPiIKQtpDqIsi49oti+K0pwJKUqlU6J1G-rcBy7U8uWrJCuWl8lo-bJKo+6rTymk8zw+48mrhMS-0k6TpU6+SeuENiYDUVS-lWLSpSYLieO1YGpvMmabLs-azJ3d6DuoGafLhhGkYKQKnR2k49qei8jrihLaXO1LEopuBEa4+7HsBiqvsit6XIaoWqx+gHBP+v7gYAlrxLycGOu5LqFKUrDU1UhjHhRgBZZNU3wABNRiJpEqBsdJzy8fmgXFtF+2VrJQLDe5nWAq22n0VCmSCeF5mTsS5KObZzX3cYvnUCthoXqdkWrfFkr6u3SXXLnaQit8fs7DkAhjm4EhnIIYHWryCQQAoEAIEwNjCWQUBHj4VoAAVHgQehkHcFRWhIJRO6rxJzjRHkmD9OAABkVjgZBC5URhB+H2KYCYBYwBWApkBgHBaDgKu4HQRINGOdQJ5YgpaBIZUADFcAeMIN67ovwkrkB1XQFQAHVOngIsyGYDuXRTxdCUF3MA9AB5oBLHgFu5wCgPFnkhBeIAABW9A7BMA3moAAirQCA8BEHzz3iABYvwThd1yEfFQr9MA4CBJ-ZKOZkAAA5JhV1oU4OAn9ziYC7rQz0JwIwzyroaPB8BYE107igWiBh+waA0K-UQoibqwKvggpAc9kGMHQKgLeO9iFDFWDgsRM8NFIOIY+Bh6gmFIHGFXbeJBUAolWIifg6iQCemuK-UkAAVEgiQpGaOIRGXeABJUoZgmBgDobXVspQWD6EIYwDgHAgA)

```bash
--parser babel
```

**Input:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px 60px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
  `;


function ButtonClick() {
  

  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios.get("https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies")
      .then((response) => {
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from(new Set(response.data))});
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs</h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.bond_actor}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
      <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((user) => (
              <li key={user.id}>{user.movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```

I tried an Array, and a Set in fetchData, but I'm having trouble implementing it. I'm just not sure if I'm putting the proper code in the right place. I would appreciate it if I get some assistance on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to map you required data and filter out unique values from objects. I have update code it should work for you.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";

const Button = styled.button`
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 60px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
`;

function ButtonClick() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState();
  const fetchData = (type) => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://iznfqs92n3.execute-api.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v2/movies"
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const mappedData = (response.data || [])
          .map((item) => item[type] || (type === "directors" && item.director))
          .filter((newItem) => newItem);
        setUsers({ [type]: Array.from([...new Set(mappedData)]) });
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Bond Database</h2>
        <h5>
          Click on the buttons to see the list of all the bond movie's
          directors, bond actors, release year, and title songs
        </h5>

        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("bond_actor")}>Bond Actors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.bond_actor?.map((user, index) => (
              <li key={index}>{user}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("directors")}>Directors</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.directors?.map((director) => (
              <li key={director}>{director}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("title_song")}>Songs</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.title_song?.map((title_song) => (
              <li key={title_song}>{title_song}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => fetchData("movie_year")}>Movie Year</Button>
        {users && (
          <ul>
            {users?.movie_year?.map((movie_year) => (
              <li key={movie_year}>{movie_year}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ButtonClick;
```